# How to select multiple items and drag them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement multiple drag and drop items using React and KendoReact, but for some reason my multiple selection selects on every click and if I select multiple items they don't move, any ideas why this behavior is occurring and how to fix it? Here is code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Grid,
  GridColumn as Column,
  getSelectedState,
  getSelectedStateFromKeyDown,
} from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { DragAndDrop } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
import { DraggableRow } from './draggable-row';
import { DragHandleCell } from './drag-handle-cell';
import products from './products.json';
import { getter } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
const DATA_ITEM_KEY = 'ProductID';

export const ReorderContext = React.createContext({
  reorder: () => {},
  dragStart: () => {},
});

const SELECTED_FIELD = 'selected';
const idGetter = getter(DATA_ITEM_KEY);
const selectionModes = [
  {
    value: 'single',
    label: 'Single selection mode',
  },
  {
    value: 'multiple',
    label: 'Multiple selection mode',
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = React.useState(products);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(
    products.map((dataItem) =>
      Object.assign(
        {
          selected: false,
        },
        dataItem
      )
    )
  );
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = React.useState({});
  const [dragEnabled, setDragEnabled] = React.useState(true);
  const [cellEnabled, setCellEnabled] = React.useState(true);
  const [selectionMode, setSelectionMode] = React.useState(
    selectionModes[1].value
  );

  const onSelectionChange = (event) => {
    const newSelectedState = getSelectedState({
      event,
      selectedState: selectedState,
      dataItemKey: DATA_ITEM_KEY,
    });
    setSelectedState(newSelectedState);
  };

  const onKeyDown = (event) => {
    const newSelectedState = getSelectedStateFromKeyDown({
      event,
      selectedState: selectedState,
      dataItemKey: DATA_ITEM_KEY,
    });
    setSelectedState(newSelectedState);
  };

  const reorder = (dataItem, direction) => {
    if (activeItem === dataItem) {
      return;
    }

    let reorderedData = gridData.slice();
    let prevIndex = reorderedData.findIndex((p) => p === activeItem);
    let nextIndex = reorderedData.findIndex((p) => p === dataItem);
    reorderedData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    reorderedData.splice(
      Math.max(nextIndex + (direction === 'before' ? -1 : 0), 0),
      0,
      activeItem || reorderedData[0]
    );
    setGridData(reorderedData);
  };

  const dragStart = (dataItem) => {
    setActiveItem(dataItem);
  };

  return (
    <ReorderContext.Provider
      value={{
        reorder: reorder,
        dragStart: dragStart,
      }}
    >
      <DragAndDrop>
        <Grid
          style={{
            height: '400px',
          }}
          data={data.map((item) => ({
            ...item,
            [SELECTED_FIELD]: selectedState[idGetter(item)],
          }))}
          // dataItemKey={'ProductID'}
          // dataItemKey={DATA_ITEM_KEY}
          selectedField={SELECTED_FIELD}
          selectable={{
            enabled: true,
            drag: dragEnabled,
            cell: cellEnabled,
            mode: selectionMode,
          }}
          rowRender={(row, rowProps) => (
            <DraggableRow elementProps={row.props} {...rowProps} />
          )}
          onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        >
          <Column title="" width="80px" cell={DragHandleCell} />
          <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="60px" />
          <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250px" />
          <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
          <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
          <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
        </Grid>
      </DragAndDrop>
    </ReorderContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

And a runnable example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4eqmga-3ptq6m?file=app/main.jsx

Comment: https://github.com/sojinantony01/react-multi-row-dragable-table-antd try this

Comment: https://sojinantony01.github.io/react-multi-row-dragable-table-antd/ live demo

Comment: I tried it but cannot implement the same logic in my example